# how do I install a ruby plugin in Powershell?

Tags: ruby, plugins, windows-7, powershell

I'd like to install the [scheduler_daemon plugin](https://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon). I get to this part of the instructions and I'm stuck.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon.git
# Install required gems
gem install daemons rufus-scheduler eventmachine chronic -s http://gemcutter.org
```

Error: 
`The term 'script/plugin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...`

Ok, so I preface it with Ruby:

```
PS>ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon.git
D:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- script/plugin (LoadError)
```

I then tried `ruby script/plugin install calendar_helper` but got the same error. I tried putting script/plugin in quotes. I tried putting a trailing slash. I tried using `http://github...`. There are other things I've tried, to no avail.

What do I need to do to install a Ruby plugin via Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Found it shortly after: `rails plugin install git://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon.git`

The thing I've learned about Rails: any info that isn't on an official Rails site may be very outdated. Go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ first, second, then stackoverflow, then the rest of the net.

Answer (score 0):

Before Rails 3

```
 ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon.git
```

should work, provided you are at the root of your Rails app.

From Rails 3 onwards, this has become `rails plugin install`